# After pressing the download button, nothing is happening

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime

[image: screenshot of the page I'm accesing]

I am trying to download the Qt linux version of the ArcGIS, I press on the download button but nothing's downloaded. Anyone faced such a problem before? I've tried from 2 browsers and changed the network connection and restarted the page.

Comment: Works for me and I’m only on an iPhone.

Comment: I'll try downloading from a different platform then transferring it to my Ubuntu. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nabil. Did you manage to download the SDK?

Comment: Hi, I downloaded from android phone. I tried from windows also it didn't work. I downloaded using my android phone then transferred the file to my linux.
 Thanks.